# How to use Reflection to retrieve a property?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I use Reflection to get a static readonly property? It's access modifier (public, protected, private) is not relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the GetProperty() method of the Type class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx

```
Type t = typeof(MyType);
PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("Foo");
object value = pi.GetValue(null, null);

class MyType
{
 public static string Foo
 {
   get { return "bar"; }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Type.GetProperty() with BindingFlags.Static.  Then PropertyInfo.GetValue().

Answer (score 3):

Just like you would get any other property (for example, look at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/987982/50079)).

The only difference is that you would provide `null` as the target object when calling `GetValue`.