# In C# How to dynamically specify a member of a object, like obj["abc"] in PHP

Tags: c#, member

Say I have a class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string name = "";
    public int age = 20;
}
```

now I want a function that can dynamically get the value of a specified member of Employee

```
public class Util<T>
{
    public static string GetValue(T obj, string member)
    {
        // how to write
    }
}
```

so that I can use it like

```
Employee p1 = new Employee();
string a = Util<Employee>.GetValue(p1, "age"); // a should be "20"
```

How to do it? like access member use obj["???"] in PHP

Comment: I never knew you could use `$obj['property']` in PHP. Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: That sounds like associative arrays. I thought PHP syntax for dynamic member access was $obj->$var.
Are you trying to get values from an anonymous type? If so, it might be easier to try the "Cast by Example" trick.

Comment: something like $_REQUEST["type"] in PHP (well its not a object of a class...),  or like actionscript3

Comment: While this is possible in C# using reflection (see the answers below), it's unidiomatic and very verbose. I suggest that you solve your problem in a different way. If you need a loosely-typed collection of properties indexed by string, for example, try a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Comment: Here is my problem: I have several collections ObserverableCollection<Employee> <Student> <Patient>, and I need a function to calculate the average age of these kind of collections. since all the class of Employ/Student/Patient has the member of "age", the function will looks like: int ave = GetAverage(students, "age")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection. Take a look here:

[Reflection: Property Value by Name](http://www.karpach.com/Reflection-Property-Value.htm)

Oh, and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987982/c-how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-string-property-via-reflection)
 in our very own SO!

**Update**

Sigh... It's all about "teh codez"... Here you go:

```
p1.GetType().GetProperty("age").GetValue(p1,null);
```

But do check the links, there's stuff to learn!

Comment: What about for a static class?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's called Reflection. See [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
// get value of private field: private double _number
int value = (int)typeof(p1).InvokeMember("age",
BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
null, p1, null);
```

or

```
 // Get the FieldInfo of MyClass.
 FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(p1).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

 var age = myFields[i].GetValue(p1);
```

check [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Where does the parameter "age" come from?  You should think about other designs where the choice of property isn't stored in a string.

For example, if you want to display a drop-down allowing the user to choose a column to sort by, you would want to pass a `Comparer<Employee>` from the view to the model, this will be much MUCH faster, and also use the correct numeric sort instead of lexicographic.

Comment: Here is my problem: I have several collections ObserverableCollection<Employee> <Student> <Patient>, and I need a function to calculate the average age of these kind of collections. since all the class of Employ/Student/Patient has the member of "age", the function will looks like:  int ave = GetAverage(students, "age")

Comment: @demaxSH: It would be much better to pass a lambda, like `GetAverage(students, s => s.age)`.  You can probably even find a function in the LINQ library that will already do the averaging for you.

Answer (score 0):

While I see a lot of usage of reflection here, maybe in your usecase you can do

```
object p1 = new Employee();
var employee = p1 as Employee;
// optionally you could do a nullcheck
string a = employee.age; // a should be "20"
```

Reflection works, but in your case I would just not go that far. but maybe you need generics then yes, go with reflection instead.