# How to get property name and its value?

Tags: c#, loops, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How can I get the value of a string property via Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987982/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-string-property-via-reflection)

```
public class myClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}


public void myMethod(myClass data)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Type t = data.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
    {
        myDict[pi.Name] = //...value appropiate sended data.
    }
}
```

Simple class with 3 `properties`. I send object of this class.
How can I i loop get all `property names` and its values e.g. to one `dictionary`?

Comment: I have seen this question answered so many times :(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987982/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-string-property-via-reflection

Comment: @daryal Then link the question as a duplicate and vote to close?

Comment: btw, there are some naming conventions in .Net

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
    {
        myDict[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(data,null)?.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: @AdrianIftode, It looks like we all got one (including the OP). I've up-voted you to compensate.

Comment: can be data be an extension?

Comment: @Demodave, Probably yes, depends what you want. Do you want to create a dictionary from the properties of an object of `myClass` type?

Comment: If you have a null value it'll throw an exception when you call ToString(), so you should change it to pi.GetValue(data,null) != null ? pi.GetValue(data,null).ToString() : "";

Answer (score 11):

This should do what you need:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Type myClassType = myClass.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = myClassType.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + property.GetValue(myClass, null));
}
```

**Output:**

> Name: a, Value: 0
>
> Name: b, Value: 0
>
> Name: c, Value: 0