# Get property value by string

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How can I get the value of a string property via Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987982/c-sharp-how-can-i-get-the-value-of-a-string-property-via-reflection)
>   [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

When I have a string, I want to compare this with all my property names. When there is a match, how can I return the value of this property?

Class = Setting

Setting has 2 properties.

When I have a string that is the same as one of the propertie names. How can I return the value of that property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to read property names and values. For example to get a list of public properties on a type you could use the [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb) method:

```
var properties = typeof(Setting);
foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    // here you can access the name of the property using prop.Name
    // if you want to access the value you could use the prop.GetValue method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get properties of your class, You can achieve this by some thing like.

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);


foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  if (propertyInfo.Name == yourString)
  {
       return yourString;
  }
}
```