# C# Calling a Variable from another Variable

Tags: c#, variables

```
public class Car
 {
     public string Color { get; set; }
     public string Model { get; set; }
 }
```

How I call "Car.Color" or "Car.Model" from a variable?

Ex.

```
string MyVariable = "Color";
MyListBox.Items.Add(Car.Model); //It Works Ok
MyListBox.Items.Add(Car.MyVariable); // How??
```

Regards.

Comment: You want reflection or a dictionary.

Comment: Just to clarify anyone else (it took me a min to figure out) I think he is asking about using reflection to search for the property selected in `MyVariable` and add that to the list box.

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF? Binding is the solution to this, but it is different depending on which you are using.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you Could do Color MyColor = Car.Color; maybe if thats your goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property value by string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390697/get-property-value-by-string)

Comment: I'm using Winforms. Car (more complex) is a query's result (LINQ to Dataset). Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd have to use reflection. For example:

```
var property = typeof(Car).GetProperty(MyVariable);
MyListBox.Items.Add(property.GetValue(Car)); // .NET 4.5
```

Or:

```
var property = typeof(Car).GetProperty(MyVariable);
MyListBox.Items.Add(property.GetValue(Car, null)); // Prior to .NET 4.5
```

(Your sample code would be clearer if you used a different name for the variable `Car` than the type `Car`, mind you. Ditto `MyVariable` which doesn't look like a variable in normal .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: @karmany: It's worth noting that this is the sort of thing you don't want to be doing most of the time. We don't really have enough context to know whether it's the most appropriate approach *here*, or whether binding would be better as Scott suggested.

Comment: Car is a query's result (LINQ to Dataset). When a user selects "Color" Field (in the query), I want to fill a list (MyListBox) only with the "Color" Field.

Comment: @karmany : Then that sounds like you *should* be using binding instead. Set the display property based on the query, but actually populate the listbox with the full `Car` references.

Comment: Jon, your code shows: "No overload for GetValue method..." I don't know what is "binking instead". I will seek more information.

Comment: yeah this seems like using symbolic references in Perl... tread carefully.

Comment: This code works fine:
       var property = typeof(Car).GetProperty(MyVariable);
       MyListBox.Items.Add(property.GetValue(Car,null));
if you could edit your answer. Very thanks!!

Comment: @karmany : My code should work fine in .NET 4.5; the overload was added then. I'll edit the answer to make that clear.